# Creating A Power Scaling System

Tags: super-powers, power-scaling

Okay, I want to create a power scaling system that can look at the characters of my story, and compare them to each other, as well as that of a regular human. I want it to be complex, but simple enough to understand and see which characters are overall more powerful than others, and see which fields different characters beat each other in. I'd like six different stats, as well as a total, akin to Pokémon. Unlike Pokemon, here's what the stats and their antitheses are:

- Offense vs Defense
- Range vs Speed
- Sensory vs Stealth

Or do you have a better idea? And I'd like to see with and without regards to inherent advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Are you making a card game?  Is balance desirable?

Comment: No, it's settle debates about power between fans of my work.

Comment: How about to add some other stats like intelligence, adaptability, resourcefulness and experience, I believe that a relatively weak but smart enough character can beat a strong but dumb character.

Comment: Yeah, those could work.

Comment: Ummmm... Gwent.

Comment: Maybe  use fields, like fire, water, mind, speed... Each one is boosted like from 0 to 5 and then you can calculate both the power and the vulnerability. a 3 fire can't defeat a 4 Water but a 5 fire can boil a 3 water

Comment: Fans of your work? What kind of work? videogames/books/RPG? You need a little more context to make this question make sense to people who might give you answers.  Usually, this kind of thing is more about "shooting the bull" ("Yeah, the Punisher is way cooler than Batman, and DC sucks."/"That's a lie!")

Comment: Is this a computer game? Visually, what are the limitations?

Comment: It's for a comic book that I want to see an animated adaptation of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at a scale for power, what do you *want* to measure?  Or perhaps the better addendum to the question is "What do you find important enough about the characters to measure and compare?"

As given, your six criteria will work.  Personally, I might split Range and Speed into two pairs -- Range/Melee and Speed/Endurance -- but that is me personally.

### Made to Measure

#### Case Study

Naruto, as one example, does have an official source that rates their characters and compares them in the area that the series considers to be important to their shinobi forces.  While it does not necessarily indicate who will win a fight, it does show in a more empirical form who is better in what field of study.

For Naruto, they are more so guides and insights into specialties.  It does not necessarily tell you who will win a fight between two characters unless the difference is too great.

The actual categories aren't relevant for you, but the concept of the idea is -- categories need to reflect what is important in the character's world.

#### Comic Logic

Based on your comment about wanting it for a comic book, then there are some clues there.  If they have powers, you have some ideas that involve powers of some sort.  The key is that these measures are not necessarily opposed.  A really strong character may have a high ranking in opposing stats because they are just that strong.

- **Offence/Defence**:  You mentioned already.  Assuming powers, a reflection to how a character uses their powers when it comes time to use them or their general style of combat
- **Potential/Insight**: The dichotomy of how strong a character's power is versus their knowledge of how to use it, or possibly their required secondary powers.  A weak character might have little potential, but a lot of insight in using what they have.
- **Physical/Special**:  How strong is your character in physical combat versus how strong they are in their powers.  Do they bust out the martial arts or weapons, or do they unleash their powers when it comes time to throw down.
- **Luck/Fate**:  Does a character utilize luck and improvisation to achieve their aims or do they use careful study and planning to do their thing?

This is not an exhaustive list naturally, but intended to be a general guide.  Different genres of comics or even individual titles would have different things that are relevant to compare.

Comment: Sounds pretty good. I will take your advice.